# Filter feed by site

Tags: feature-request, android-app

It would be nice if I could filter my feed according to the sites I'm interested in. I can select what site to look at. I can select a list of sites to be included in the menu. But the feed continues to send me Qs from all sorts of sites, including many I have no interest in following.

Comment: Also, please take note that there's currently no active development on mobile apps since last year.